# Cannot get nvidia drivers to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04

I have tried everything and literally followed this tutorial: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html 10 times from top to bottom and I still can't get my nvidia drivers installed. I am running ubuntu 13.04. It should be noted that when I type:

```
lsmod|grep nvidia
```

I get an output of:

```
nvidia       11309139 0
```

I can still see the screen, as stated in my other question, and I can still interact with folders on my desktop and open terminal. My screen looks like this:
[image]

That is all I see, and I'm thrown constant "Ubuntu has experienced a severe problem" and then I am asked to send logs from nvidia. So, I'm guessing it is installed.

Comment: What is the output of `lshw -c video | grep -in configuration`?

Comment: `11   Configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0`
`23   Configuration: driver=i915 latence=0`

Comment: Open `Software & Updates` and Select `Additional Drivers` tab. Please post a screenprint of that window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to get it to work perfectly and here is the following process I took to install it:

Go to the Nvidia site and download the correct java for Linux (take not of its name and location)

After downloading, press *Ctrl + alt + F1* and you will be brought to a terminal like window

*Login and then cd to the location of your Nvidia file*

Type the following commands:

**Close the X Server:**
`sudo service lightdm stop`

**chmod the Nvidia File:**
`chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xx.run`

**Run the Nvidia File**: 
`sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xx.run`

Note: You may get an error telling you that Nouveau needs to be disabled. Just follow the prompts and it will offer an option to disable it automatically. After this type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart the computer. Follow the above steps again and it should now be installed.

*However*

Your resolution will now probably be completely tiny due to it now being in power save mode. To fix this, perform the following:

**cd to xorg.conf file:**
`cd /etc/X11`

**Editing the xorg.conf file**
`sudo gedit xorg.conf`

You should now have something open with something like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

back up this file and then you will now need to edit it

**Get you monitor files**

```
sudo apt-get install hwinfo
sudo hwinfo --monitor
```

Take not of the attributes that show and then enter them into your xorg.conf file.
You want to remoce the power saving option "DPMS" and update the HorizSync and VertRefresh to your monitors settings.

My Monitor section looked like the following:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 72.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 60.0
EndSection
```

Such a pain just to install a Nvidia driver considering Windows just uses a simple installation program and its done.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` instead of editing the xorg.conf file yourself?